# Proper syntax for Handlebars expression within block helper. Specifically {{#link-to}}

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

What is the proper syntax to use an objects property as the 'link-to' or other value in a handlebars expression? For example, I want to use `{{page.slug}}`

```
<ul class='main-menu'>
{{#each model as |page|}}
    <li>
        {{#link-to 'HERE'}}
            {{page.title}}
        {{/link-to}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Also, this may be a *hacky* way of making a menu, but is more about how I came to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `link-to` is:

```
{{link-to ROUTE_NAME (dynamic-segment OR model)}}
```

So what you can do is pass the slug as the second parameter:

```
{{link-to 'page' page.slug}}
```

Which will call the `model` hook inside your `page` route, passing the slug in `params` object:

```
model(params) {
  console.log(params.slug); // logs your slug
}
```

Also, you need to specify the dynamic segment of your route in the router:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('page', { path: '/:slug' });
});
```

However you name the dynamic segment in the router (in this case `'slug'`), will be the name of the property in the `params` object passed into the model

Comment: In my case it ended up just straight: {{#link-to page.slug}}...   : )

Comment: Good, then its solved :). One thing to note is that your way works if you have a route with the name being whatever `page.slug` is.

Comment: Yep! But I'm sure your more thorough example will come in handy soon enough.